# Chaining jquery css Changes

Tags: jquery, css

Hey guys i am trying to make a slide in slide out on menu list items.
And i am using transition to give an animation to css settings.
Now the point is how can i do something using jquery after the css has been applied.
i have written this code but it seems to work at the same time.
I want is that the `#homeContainer` width should be 0px and then the `#galleryContainer` width starts to increase.
thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#galleryListItem').click(function(){
    $('#homeContainer').css('width','0px');
    $('#galleryContainer').css('width','600px');
});});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function to put a delay (I used 500ms in the example below):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#galleryListItem').click(function(){
    $('#homeContainer').css('width','0px');
    setTimeout(function () { $('#galleryContainer').css('width','600px'); }, 500);
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` for this to delay the application of css to the `#galleryContainer`, as suggested by malkassem, and you can also use `setInterval` to gradually increase the width(using an incrementing width value) of that container, to achieve the slide in effect, something along the lines of

```
var galleryWidth = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    galleryWidth += 50;
    $('#galleryContainer').css('width', galleryWidth + 'px');
}, 500);
```

But I think, in this case, what you really should use is jQuery's `animate` method ([Reference](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)). Like so:

```
$('#galleryListItem').click(function () {
    $('#homeContainer').animate({
        width: "0"
    }, 2000);
    $('#galleryContainer').show().animate({
        width: "600px"
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aw5r9/2/)